# CMake Generator Expressions and CONFIG variable query

Tags: cmake

This CMake Doc : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html tells us that :

```
$<CONFIG> Configuration name.
```

and that :

```
Conditional generator expressions depend on a boolean condition that must be 0 or 1.

$<condition:true_string> Evaluates to true_string if condition is 1. Otherwise evaluates to the empty string.

$<IF:condition,true_string,false_string> New in version 3.8.

Evaluates to true_string if condition is 1. Otherwise evaluates to false_string.

Typically, the condition is a boolean generator expression. For instance,

$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG_MODE> expands to DEBUG_MODE when the Debug configuration is used, and otherwise expands to the empty string.
```

If I understand correctly, in Visual Studio, if I'm switching from Debug to Release this line :

```
$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG_MODE>
```

Should also expand to DEBUG_MODE, isn't it ? because CONFIG will contain, according to my understanding "Release" and it's a non empty string, thus it will expand to Debug, than this  last will make the first generator expression expand to DEBUG_MODE because of this statement in the documentation :

> $condition:true_string Evaluates to true_string if condition is 1.
> Otherwise evaluates to the empty string.

I know I'm wrong, please help me to understand how it works.

Comment: `because CONFIG will contain, according to my understanding "Release" and it's a non empty string, thus it will expand to Debug`  but `$<CONFIG:cfgs>

    1 if config is any one of the entries in cfgs, else 0.`

Comment: @KamilCuk the doc says : $<condition:true_string> Evaluates to true_string if condition is 1. Otherwise evaluates to the empty string

Comment: The doc says `$<CONFIG:cfgs>      1 if config is any one of the entries in cfgs, else 0.`. I do not understand `CONFIG` is not a condition (in the "grammar" sense).

Comment: CMake is really a strange beast ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because CONFIG will contain

`CONFIG` does not contain, it's not a condition, it's a specific [Variable query](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#variable-queries) with special rules.

> ```
> $<CONFIG:cfgs>
>
> 1 if config is any one of the entries in cfgs, else 0. [...]
> ```

---

Let's say it works like this:

- extract the parts `A` and `B` like `$<A:B>`
- if part `A` is `CONFIG`
  - then do stuff related to `CONFIG`
- if part `A` is, for example, `STREQUAL`
  - then do stuff on `B` related to `STREQUAL`.
- for each case ...
- otherwise it's a `condition`, so if it's `1`, then return `B`, otherwise empty string.